# Prevent user to type null in required textfield with validation

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to tell knockout that if a user typing null in a required textfield it will not be valid.

This will just force user to type anything but whitespaces.

```
ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
```

EDIT:

I've tried this without any success:

```
self.test = ko.observable().extend({ validation: { validator: self.notNullOrEmpty, message: '' } });

self.notNullOrEmpty = function (val) {
   return val != 'null' || val != '';
};
```

Exception:

```
http://localhost:50566/Scripts/knockout.validation.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object expected
```

Comment: you can write your custom validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this custom validation.

```
ko.validation.rules['notNullOrEmpty'] = {
  validator: function (val) {
    return ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(val) || val !== 'null';
  },
  message: 'invalid input'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZV7HU/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get error when trying the fiddle: Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/master/Src/knockout.validation.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. (index):1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rules' of undefined (index):30
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://raw.github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/master/Src/knockout.validation.js".

Comment: I don't why its giving error. at my side working fine. I have updated the knockout.validation.js cdn.